# How to translate the following query to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_reqstats` (
  `sdate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deptID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `opID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `requests` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `taken` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `declined` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `initiated` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `initiated_taken` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rateit` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ratings` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sdate`,`deptID`,`opID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I wonder in fact part :

```
 PRIMARY KEY (sdate,deptID,opID)
```

Here the problem occurs because the

Comment: What version of postgresql? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

A few issues:

- You won't have `IF NOT EXISTS` unless you're using 9.1 or higher.
- PostgreSQL doesn't know what `int(10)` means, you just want `int`.
- PostgreSQL doesn't know what `unsigned` means.
- Backticks for quoting identifiers is a MySQLism, most databases use double quotes (the standard).
- `smallint` is supported but [`int` is recommended](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT) unless you are tight on disk space.

So something like this should work:

```
create table "p_reqstats" (
    "sdate" int NOT NULL,
    "deptID" int NOT NULL,
    "opID" int NOT NULL,
    "requests" int NOT NULL,
    "taken" smallint NOT NULL,
    "declined" smallint NOT NULL,
    "message" smallint NOT NULL,
    "initiated" smallint NOT NULL,
    "initiated_taken" smallint NOT NULL,
    "rateit" smallint NOT NULL,
    "ratings" smallint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("sdate","deptID","opID")
);
```

If you needed the extra space that an unsigned value would give you
then you could use `bigint` instead of `int`.